# Delphi: delete inherited TStringGrid

Tags: delphi

I want to have a custom StringGrid element.
I created a class:

```
type
  TClassStringGrid = class(TCustomControl)
  ...
```

with

```
constructor TClassStringGrid.Create(AOwner: TForm);
begin
    inherited Create(nil);
    myGroupBox1 := TGroupBox.Create(AOwner);
    myGroupBox1.Parent := AOwner;
    myStringGrid1 := TStringGrid.Create(self);
    myStringGrid1.Parent := myGroupBox1;
    myStringGrid1.Options := myStringGrid1.Options + [goEditing];
end;

destructor TClassStringGrid.Destroy;
begin
    if myStringGrid1 <> nil then  begin
      FreeAndNil(myStringGrid1);
    end;

    if myGroupBox1 <> nil then  begin
      DestroyComponents;
      FreeAndNil(myGroupBox1);
  end;

  // Call the parent class destructor
  inherited;

end;
```

I created a class in Form1 and show it. It works. But if I put some value into the StringGrid (Form1) and then try to close Form1 I get an exception "the element has no parent window" in `FreeAndNil(myStringGrid1);`.
What is wrong by Destroy?
I would be thankfull for any information you can provide me.

Comment: why inherited Create(nil); and not inherited Create(aOwner) ?

Comment: Ownership is badly messed up here. You create to sub controls and have them both owned. But then you take charge of destroying those sub controls. 1. Pass `AOwner` to inherited constructor. 2. Pass `nil` as `Owner` for the two sub controls. 3. Call `Free` on the two sub controls in the destructor. 4. Remove all that other code from the destructor.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I did three steps:1. `inherited Create(AOwner);` 2. `myGroupBox1 := TGroupBox.Create(nil);`3. `myStringGrid1.Free;` But I still have the error.

Comment: That's not what I said though is it. Plus you did not show the code in your form. Perhaps that is wrong too. Maybe time to visit the [help] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Actually, there are many other problems here too. You have to derive your constructor from the virtual constructor introduced in `TComponent`. Otherwise the control cannot be streamed. You cannot assume that the control will have an owner. You must not set the parent of your control in the constructor, although you can set the parent of the sub controls. But only to your control or one of the sub controls. If you want to create a custom string grid I'd expect you to derive from one of the base grid classes. Frankly you are a very long way from working code here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to show a String grid in a Group box on this control, then this is how it should look like:

```
type
  TMyStringGrid = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FGroupBox: TGroupBox;
    FStringGrid: TStringGrid;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

constructor TMyStringGrid.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FGroupBox := TGroupBox.Create(Self);
  FGroupBox.Parent := Self;
  FStringGrid := TStringGrid.Create(Self);
  FStringGrid.Parent := FGroupBox;
end;
```

In this manner, your newly designed control is owner and parent of the sub controls. Destruction is done automatically because of that.

Comment: Technically the parent of the string grid is the group box